# In Elite: Dangerous on Xbox One (not PC) how do you move up and down in the galactic map

Tags: xbox-one, elite-dangerous

This is specific to the Xbox One controls for Elite: Dangerous

You can move around the galactic map with the sticks, but there doesn't appear to be a way to move up or down (I've been selecting nearby stars above or below the plane).

How do you move up and down in the galactic map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the [image: xbox gamepad x button] button to toggle vertical navigation in the galaxy map.

Comment: Ben, this is the correct answer. You have to press the "X" button on the Xbox One gamepad to toggle vertical navigation in the galaxy map. Why the downvote and flagging of this question?

Comment: @Ben I've checked and this works `x` toggles the up/down movement in the galaxy map. This is the answer I needed, Cheers!